# Getting TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm creating a datatable to display the database results from the backend.

```
        <div class="box" id="table-box">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="shortcodes no-top-padding">
                    <div class="dataTables_wrapper table-bordered table-striped dt-bootstrap">
                        <table id="branchTable" class="table table-hover dataTable"
                               cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Telephone</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm sending the AJAX request to the backend and it returns the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    alert("here");
    $('#branchTable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "searchDelay": 1000,
        "ajax": "controller/listing-branch-controller.php",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id", "visible": false},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "address"},
            {"data": "telephone"},
            {"data": "email"}

        ],
        "language": {
            "searchPlaceholder": "by Name"
        },
        "pageLength": 10
    });
});
```

But i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I have imported all the necessary script files as required as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Data Tables -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo(getConfiguration('site_url')); ?>/js/dataTables.buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm failing to find where has went wrong.
Any idea?

Comment: Looks like typo. Try ".dataTable" instead of ".DataTable"

Comment: I did. Keep getting the error

Comment: Check your paths to the files are correct. The DataTables library is not being loaded for some reason. We can't tell you exactly why that is with the information you've shown us/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### POSSIBLE CAUSES

- jQuery DataTables library is missing
- jQuery library is loaded **after** jQuery DataTables
- Multiple versions of jQuery library is loaded

#### SOLUTION

Include only one version of jQuery library version 1.7 or newer **before** jQuery DataTables.

#### LINKS

Please see [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: $(…).DataTable is not a function](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
// you have to add datatables librairie's in your page by adding those two lines

 <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```